# how to fix error "No task registered for key RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage" when my app is closed for getting fcm message

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

my AndroidManifest is

[image]

in index i wrote
 `AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => firebaseBackgroundMessage);`

that `firebaseBackgroundMessage` is a function as below

```
export async function firebaseBackgroundMessage(message: RemoteMessage) { 
let notif=message['data']; console.log(notif); return Promise.resolve();}
```

i getting fcm message in background and foreground state 
but

in closed state is not received any fcm message 
and 
in console log i have this error

```
 No task registered for key RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage
```

any solution?
thank a lot for your help ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i have a make a mistake in config and i put

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => firebaseBackgroundMessage);
```

in main.js page and it must be in index.js

and i do it
i am so happy to fix it...

thanks to me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling a lot to handle push notification when app is killed, eventually I got the solution.

If we really observe carefully we don't need to register headless task because the package react-native-firebase is already handling it.

All we have to do is add the following lines in your MainActivity.java on native side.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    intent.putExtras(this.getIntent());
}
```

I have a git repo link of mine which has complete set up of notifications, works in all cases i.e, foreground, background, Even app is killed.

https://github.com/venkatesh-u/DeepLinking

Comment: i saw your project(thanks a lot) and i build my project again(with i put onNewIntent in MainActivity) but i get that error  "No task registered for key RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage"

Comment: See We really don't need that RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage (headlessTask), Without that we can handle the notifications in all cases i.e, foreground, background, App killed. That's what I put in my case(above link)