# How can I wake up a calling app that is closed when a call enters the phone through the app

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, voximplant

I am trying to create a video calling app using react native for front-end and firebase with voximplant for back-end. I have been able to implement the video call in such a way that when there is an incoming call, the app will log the user in by itself while the user is logged out and navigate to the calling screen so the user can answer the call. But this happens only when the app is already opened. What I want to do is that, when the app is closed I want an incoming call to open the app and then navigate to the calling screen so the callee can answer the call. I have tried push notification as recomended by voximplant but there is something I am missing. Please I need help with this. Thanks in advance.

The code I wrote for this in my login file is below. When the app is closed and I tried to call to see if the app will wake or be opened through the push notification I have implemented it doesn't work, instead it logs into the consele 'warning: FCM headlesstask not registered'. This is the code below:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Pressable, Text, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Voximplant} from 'react-native-voximplant';
import { ACC_NAME, APP_NAME } from "../../constants";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const LoginScreen = () => {
    const[username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const[passsword, setPassword] = useState('');

    const voximplant = Voximplant.getInstance();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const msg = messaging();

    let token = '';

    useEffect(async() => {
               
        const connect = async () => {
            const status = await voximplant.getClientState();
            if(status === Voximplant.ClientState.DISCONNECTED) {
                await voximplant.connect();
            } else if(status === Voximplant.ClientState.LOGGED_IN) {
                redirectHome();
            }
        }

        connect();
     
        pushBackgroundHandler();
        pushMessaging();
        
    }, []);

    const pushManager = async () => {
        return await msg.getToken();
    }

    const pushMessaging = async () => {
        await msg.onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
            console.log(
                `PushManager(android): onMessage: ${remoteMessage.data}`
            );
    
            await pushNotificationReceived(remoteMessage.data);
        });
    }

    const refreshToken = async () => {
        token = await msg.onTokenRefresh(remoteToken => remoteToken);   
        console.log(`PushManager(android): Refresh token: ${token}`);
    }

    const pushBackgroundHandler = async () => {
        await msg.setBackgroundMessageHandler(async(remoteMessage) => {
            console.log(
                `PushManager(android): background notification: ${
                  remoteMessage
                }`,
            );
    
            await pushNotificationReceived(remoteMessage.data);    
        });      
    }

    const pushNotificationReceived = async (notification) => {
        await tokenSignin(notification);
    }
    
    const signin = async () => {
        try {
            const user = `${username}@${APP_NAME}.${ACC_NAME}.voximplant.com`;
            const authResult = await voximplant.login(user, passsword);
            processPushToken(authResult);
            redirectHome();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            Alert.alert(e.name, `Error code: ${e.code}`);
        }
    };

    const tokenSignin = async (notification) => {
        console.log("push notification login");
        
        try {            
            const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
            const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken');
            const user = `${username}@${APP_NAME}.${ACC_NAME}.voximplant.com`;
            const authResult = await voximplant.loginWithToken(user, accessToken);
            processPushToken(authResult);
            voximplant.handlePushNotification(notification);
            
            redirectHome();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            Alert.alert(e.name, `Error code: ${e.code}`);
        }
    };

    const registerPushToken = async () => {
        token = await pushManager();
        voximplant.registerPushNotificationsToken(token);
    }

    const processPushToken = async (authResult) => {
        const loginTokens = authResult.tokens;
        
        if (loginTokens !== null) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', loginTokens.accessToken);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('refreshToken', loginTokens.refreshToken);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessExpire', loginTokens.accessExpire.toString());
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('refreshExpire', loginTokens.refreshExpire.toString());
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('username', username);
            
            registerPushToken();
        } else {
            console.error('LoginSuccessful: login tokens are invalid');
        }
    }

    const redirectHome = () => {
        navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [
                {
                    name: 'Contacts'
                }
            ]
        });
    };


    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="username" 
                style={styles.input} 
                onChangeText={setUsername}
                value={username}
                autoCapitalize="none"
            />
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="password" 
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                value={passsword}
                secureTextEntry
            />

            <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={signin}>
                <Text>Sign in</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 10,
        marginVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
        padding: 10,
        marginVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        alignItems: 'center'

    }
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your `pushBackgroundHandler` function in root **index.js** file and add following code in index.js before `AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);`

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => pushBackgroundHandler);
```

You can define and export `pushBackgroundHandler` in another file , import it to index.js and pass into `registerHeadlessTask`.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66998305/warn-no-task-registered-for-key-reactnativefirebasemessagingheadlesstask-in-reac) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097745/how-to-fix-error-no-task-registered-for-key-rnfirebasebackgroundmessage-when-m).

Comment: Thanks, but how will I get the response of the pushBackgroundHandler into my handlepushnotification as in my code, or is that not how it should be?